# unable to click disconnect wifi on my ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking, wireless, atheros

i have a problem related with wireless network on my Ubuntu 12.04.

as you can see, my wifi can connect to network, but when connected, the 'Disconnect' item on my wifi is disabled thus i can't click it to disconnect my computer from wifi network....do you know how to enable it again? thanks before :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a solution: From my point of view it seems to be an error within the last upate of the package `network-manager-gnome`, which was released 2015-02-16 (http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/main/updates/network-manager-gnome). I've tried to find the concrete error and so I've tried to use an older package version: The problem was no more present and the applet is useful as always. The problem within: The unity-greeter was also updated and breaks the package. The final solution for now is little easier:

1. Just download the deb-package for your platform (amd64 or i386) (http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/network-manager-gnome).
2. Unpack the concurrent deb-package and copy the included version of nm-applet under `/usr/bin/nm-applet` - make a copy / backup of your present version.
3. Restart your system and everything should work as always.

Comment: i thought you said before that this solution didn't work...

Comment: No then we've got a little misunderstanding here: Sorry for that. The solution don't work if done via simple shellscript. With this you get a spoken downgrade for nm-applet. So you should be able again to disconnect and use all other options as usual.

Comment: what package should i download from that link? do i have to download specific package??

Comment: Depending on the used platform of your distribution: 32bit -> http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/network-manager-gnome/download, 64bit -> http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/network-manager-gnome/download

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo ifconfig wifi0 down` and `sudo ifconfig wifi0 up`

The name wifi0 could be different use just `ifconfig` to see what it is called.

Check your logs for more info. /var/log/sys.log

Answer (score 0):

A workaround in terminal:

```
nmcli dev disconnect iface wlan0
```